# how many people are at the party

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

At a party, each person shakes hands with 5 other people. There are a total of 60 handshakes. How many people are at the party? i am lost because of the 60 hand shake that is mentioned.

Comment: Try it with shaking hands with 2 other people and a total of 5 hand shakes.

Comment: what formula will i use?

Comment: If you can't solve this problem because of the 60, try solving a simpler one.  At a party, each person shakes hands with two other people.  There are a total of 4 handshakes.  How many people are at the party?  try drawing a picture showing the people that each person shakes hands with.

Comment: This isn't about any formula (not yet). Just try it.

Comment: for that i got 3 persons in total but whats next?

Comment: Asked *again* at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/979589/18398

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The total number of handshakes multiplied by the average number of hands involved in each shake is equal to the number of people in total multiplied by the average number of handshakes undertaken by each person, as both calculations give the total number of shaken hands.